How to have flextable display a multi-line equation involving fractions?
I would like to display this in a cell of a flextable:

I'm working in an RMarkdown document that will Knit to Word. From my research, equations in flextables can either be rendered by writing in MathJax and use the flextable::compose() with  flextable::as_equation(), or by writing the equation in markdown and using ftExtra::colformat_md().   But it seems that neither full Latex or Markdown is supported here.  I've tried a handful of ways to make this render, and I feel like I can either get multi-line cells or stacked fractions :
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
date <- c("date")


library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(knitr)
library(flextable)
library(equatags)
library(officer)
library(ftExtra)

set_flextable_defaults(font.family="Times New Roman", hansi.family="Times New Roman")

FractionTable <- data.frame(
  EqnColumn=c( 
        "n = {8 \\over d^{2}}  
        \n
         \\textrm{where} d = {\\mu_2- \\mu_1 \\over \\sigma}", 
         
        "n = \\frac{8}{2} 
        \n\n
         \\textrm{where} d = {\\mu_2- \\mu_1 \\over \\sigma}", 
        ""),
  MarkdownColumn=c(
        "$n = 8/d^{2}$ \\
                   where $d= (\\mu^_{1}-\\mu^_{2})/ \\sigma$", 
        "$n = 8/d^{2}$ \\
                   where $$d= \\frac{\\mu^_{1}-\\mu^_{2}}{sigma}$$", 
        "$n = 8/d^{2}$ \\
                   where $d= \\frac{2}{3}$")
)


FractionTable %>% 
  flextable()%>%
  width(j=1:2, width=c(3,3)) %>%
  compose( j="EqnColumn", value=as_paragraph(as_equation(EqnColumn)))%>%
  colformat_md(j=2)


And this is the output:

The EqnColumn doesn't seem to listen to any newline instruction I give it, and the MarkdownColumn can't render fractions other than in-line text fractions.
